# change parameter value of dependent method in phpunit

Tags: php, phpunit

i wrote a sample test case for collection like class but weird thing about this is in my `testAdd` method that i add a item in `CustomCollectionService` and it changed my parameter too. how can this happend?

```
class CustomCollectionService
{
/**
 * @var Collection $collection
 */
public $collection;
public function makeCollection($arr)
{
    $this->collection = collect($arr);
}

/**
 * @param Collection $collection
 */
public function setCollection(Collection $collection): void
{
    $this->collection = $collection;
}


/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getCollection()
{
    return $this->collection;
}

public function add($item)
{
    return $this->collection->add($item);
}
}
```

and this is my test:

```
class CustomCollectionTest extends TestCase
{
    public $collectionService;
    public  $collection;
    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->collectionService = new CustomCollectionService();
    }

    public function testCollectionCreator()
    {
        $arr = ['sina','1',5];
        $this->assertIsArray($arr);
        return $arr;
    }

    /**
     * @param $arr
     * @depends testCollectionCreator
     */
    public function testAction($arr)
    {
        $this->collectionService->makeCollection($arr);
        $this->assertIsArray($this->collectionService->getCollection()->toArray());
        return $this->collectionService->getCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @depends testAction
     */
    public function testAdd($col)
    {
        $actualCount = $col->count();
        $this->collectionService->setCollection($col);
        $manipulatedCollection = $this->collectionService->add(['xx']);
        dump($actualCount); // 3
        dump($col->count()); //4
        $this->assertEquals($actualCount+1, $manipulatedCollection->count());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is an object. So when you pass the `$col` object to the `CollectionService` and call the `add` method within the `CollectionService`, it is still the `$col` object from your test method that is being used.

Comment: i pass $col to my class and it in my class and return it again in another variable . why parameter has been changed?

Comment: Because `$col is an object. What line of code are you referring to add exactly?

Comment: could you explain more? i know `$col` is object . this line : $manipulatedCollection = $this->collectionService->add(['xx']);

Comment: So when passing/returning objects into/from functions, you actually use the same instance of that object (technically not completely correct, but close enough). So when you add an item in one function, the item is also added in the object in another place. More info on this page: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php